# jPlaton Database API - No rows returned

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, api

I am developing a cloud based web application using the jPlaton platform and I have written a Java class where I am trying to run a query against the MySQL server. The query was first written and run in Navicat, so I am sure it is correct and returns the result I need.
But through Java and the jPlaton API it just returns the column description and no rows.

```
ArrayList res = service.getSession().executeQuery(utl.StaticString.DEFAULT_DATABASE, select.toString());
```

To I have to add or change something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jPlaton application uses a standard database which handles the general data (for example statistics regarding your app). This is the DEFAULT database. 
Are you sure you want to run your query on the DEFAULT database? 
If you just want to use the client's database, pass null as the first argument to executeQuery